# java extend and implements

Tags: java

I'm confused about the following structure, is it correct ?

```
public interface personne {} personne{}
public abstract class personneImpl implements

public interface admin {};
public class adminImpl extend personneImpl implements admin {}
```

or should it be :

```
public class adminImpl extend personneImpl implements admin, personne {}
```

Edit : the picture was just for simplification it's not a uml digram.

Comment: Since `personneImpl` already implements `personne` you do not have to add that again to `adminImpl` if it extends `personneImpl`

Comment: Really? A picture of a hand-draw diagram on a napkin?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not correct. An `extends` relation is used between `stereotype` and `metatype` in a profile definition. See p. 262 of the UML 2.5 specs. This connector shall have a solid triangle at the end. What can be seen from your drawing it is an association with a name `Extends`. That would result in an attribute within `PersonneImp`. An `<<extends>>` stereotyped connector is used only between `UseCases`.

What you probably intend to show (with respect to the 2nd code example) is a `Generalization` which is the equivalent to a Java `extend` keyword. That would have a hollow triangle where the arrow is now and have no label.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the previous answer if we have "class A extend B implement I {...}" in Java, in the diagram we have

[image]